# Hide your paths/filenames in apache

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, domain-name

in Apache 2.4, can I hide all "paths" from the browsers?

if somebody are on **https://example.com/users/list.html** it would only say **https://example.com** in the addressbar, and if someone takes a bookmark, it will also only take https://example.com and not the complete path

Preferably in the apache configuration

Comment: This is usually done with a SPA (Single-page application), not on the server side.

Comment: You can't. The server needs a way to distinguish the paths.

Comment: In addition, it's ***extremely*** bad UI design to do this. I expect to be taken to *that* page when I bookmark something, so this would piss me off as a user, and probably instantly start looking for alternatives.

Comment: @vidarlo this site isn't for the public

Comment: @AdamLarsson Even internal users probably want bookmarks.

Comment: @vidarlo not on this server, but I do understand what you're trying referring to...